# Why Spark crossjoin works right only when cached?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I was troubleshooting my Spark (2.3) app and realized that I was getting incorrect results if I did not cache the dataset after crossJoin. Do we know if it's required to cache a dataset after crossJoin?

Here's what my Dataset looks like:

```
+--------+------------+
|      id| nameGroupId|
+--------+------------+
| joe san|  6302870528|
|john san|936302870528|
+--------+------------+
```

When I execute the code below with the .cache() statement **uncommented**, the *callUDF("leftNameTokenComplement")* UDF is invoked with the following parameters, which is what I would expect:

> df1.id="joe san" & df2.id="john san"

But, when I execute the same block of code with .cache() statement **commented**, the *callUDF("leftNameTokenComplement")* UDF is invoked with the following parameters. This is crazy because the *filter()* right before the UDF would have stopped this from happening.

> df1.id="joe san" & df2.id="joe san"

```
Dataset<Row> connectedDf = sparkSession.read().json(this.workspaceDir + "connected-df");

connectedDf.as("df1")
    .crossJoin(connectedDf.as("df2"))
    //.cache() //correct results only when cached!
    .filter( "df1.id < df2.id" )
    .withColumn("leftComp", functions.callUDF("leftNameTokenComplement", col("df1.id"), col("df2.id") ))
    .filter( functions.size(col("leftComp")).equalTo(1) )       
    .withColumn("src1", functions.callUDF("firstInArray", col("leftComp")) )
    .withColumn("matchedPhonic", functions.callUDF("isNameTokenPhonicMatch", col("src1")) )
    .filter( col("matchedPhonic").equalTo(true))
    .show();
```

Comment: There is no reason for predicates to applied in a specific order you used to define them in your code, as from logical perspective it just defines of conjunction like `"df1.id < df2.id AND size(leftNameTokenComplement(df1.id, df2.id)) = 1 AND isNameTokenPhonicMatch(firstInArray(leftComp))` and as `AND` is commutative and associative optimizer is free to rearrange terms in arbitrary order. So seeing `df1.id="joe san"` and `df2.id="joe san" is hardly unusual. An unusual thing would be to see that the final results differ between these two. If that's the case, please provide a [mcve] and ...

Comment: ... execution plans ([How to make good reproducible Apache Spark examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/10938362)).  Additionally if that's indeed a correctness problem you should rather open [a JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK/issues/SPARK-27815?filter=allopenissues).